# Scheduled Tasks, CF 10 error

Tags: coldfusion, task, coldfusion-10

I have this problem and I don't know how to fix it. This is the only thing that is not working in my CF panel:

> The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
>   Error Occurred While Processing Request
>   The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.
>   Null Pointers are another name for undefined values.
>
> Resources:
>   Enable Robust Exception Information to provide greater detail about the source of errors. In the Administrator, click Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings, and select the Robust Exception Information option.
>   Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
>   Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
>   Browser     Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.20.20.20 Safari/20.36
>   Remote Address      20.20.20.20
>   Referrer    http://www.example.com/CFIDE/administrator/navserver.cfm
>   Date/Time   05-Aug-14 04:18 PM

Can somebody help me? I don't know how or for what reason happens

Comment: you mean CF Administrator?  Have you tried reinstalling CF?

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but... *what*?

Answer (score 5):

Actually got this same error. When navigating to Scheduled Tasks in CFAdmin I got the same error above. After some digging around I was able to find a bug report and even better [an article](http://www.geirman.com/2014/07/update-cf10-scheduled-tasks-manually-rather-than-by-admin-console/) that basically says replace the `\cfusion\lib\neo-cron.xml`.

In my case I just replaced the contents with:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><array length='4'><struct type='coldfusion.server.ConfigMap'></struct><boolean value='false'/><string></string><string>log,txt</string></array></data></wddxPacket>
```

Restarted my instance and it worked fine. Not sure what exactly caused this issue, but I did have about 5-6 schedules running every minute/second. Further digging I found a [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/82-null-pointers-are-another-name-for-undefined-values.htm) that talks about ColdFusion's Date functions throwing cryptic errors. Hopefully this helps anyone else in the same boat. I need to re-create all my schedules but at least it's working again.

Comment: Good answer. Small clarification, I noticed the article also mentions you *might* be able to restore it from a backup copy ie Check for `neo-cron.bak` or in a multiserver environment, grab a copy of `neo-cron.xml` from another server. Neither is guaranteed obviously, but are worth checking if you have a lot of scheduled tasks.

Comment: thanks this resolved the issue for me. Luckily my client's server vendor keeps backups of the entire system so they provided us with a working copy of the file. We replaced it and restarted CF service and all scheduled tasks came back up intact and working :)